# Can I publish my app to App store without https?

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

I am new in iOS development, and I want to publish my first app to the app store. but actually the endpoint I get from the backend guy  is only http, not https.

My friend said that it must be https or Apple will reject my app to be published in the app store ? is it true ?

If I set the NSAllowsArbitraryLoads key to YES under NSAppTransportSecurity dictionary in your .plist file. like the image below, can I still publish my app to app store using http connection ? (without https)

[image]

Comment: We have sent quite a few of them that used a non-secure HTTP with enabled flag to allow arbitrary loads. None of the apps have been rejected for that. So unless something has changed lately you should be good to go.

Comment: @MaticOblak  what do you mean with 'a non-secure HTTP with enabled flag to allow arbitrary loads'  ? do you mean to set the NSAllowsArbitraryLoads key to YES under NSAppTransportSecurity dictionary ? sorry I am confused

Comment: The "S" part in HTTPS is "Secure" HTTP protocol. Still being without it does not mean the connection is not secure or having it does not mean the connection is secure (but it usually is). Sorry for the confusion. In short: What you have pasted here should be OK and we have sent multiple applications to app store with this setup. Still Apple is Apple and may choose to reject your application for any reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using HTTP there is no reason for worries. Just place `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` into your `info.plist` file.

There is so much misleading information available. But as per my experience its more preferred & compulsory to place the `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` whether you are using `HTTP` or `HTTPs`.

**Important Note :**

- I have worked with both types of connections with HTTP & with HTTPs in both the cases I am used to add `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` into info.plist. I have never faced any sort of rejection due to it. So that I am suggesting you to do the same.

Hope this helps to everyone.

Answer (score 2):

Your friends is mostly right.  But I would say Apple *may* reject your app.  You need to provide a justification for using `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads`.
From apple's doc:

> You must supply a justification during App Store review if you set the key’s value to YES, as described in Provide Justification for Exceptions. Use this key with caution because it significantly reduces the security of your app. In most cases, it’s better to upgrade your servers to meet the requirements imposed by ATS, or at least to use a narrower exception. [source](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nsapptransportsecurity/nsallowsarbitraryloads?language=objc)